# Calcular horas con php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con dos tablas, una que es `trabajos` y otra que es `carga horaria`. En `trabajos` se le asigna una tarea a un trabajador y con una cantidad de horas estimas de trabajo:

Tabla trabajos:

```
idp | trabajadorid | tarea       | horaestamada
-----------------------------------------------
1   | 1            | cajas 20x20 |  6
2   | 1            | cajas 30x25 |  16
```

Y en la tabla `carga horaria` el trabajdor debe cargar la cantidad de horas que hace por cada trabajo.

```
idc | trabajoid | idtrabajador | horainicio | horafin | totalhora
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 1            | 09:30      | 16:00   | 
2   | 1         | 1            | 08:00      | 17:00   |
```

Bueno, lo que trato de hacer es tener un total de horas para poder multiplicarla por el valor que va a tener la hora. Ejemplo: Un trabajador trabaja 7hs 30m y no se como obtener un numero para darle un valor.

Ese calor `totalhora` lo tengo que sumar al final de cada trabajo para comparar las horas estimadas con las horas totales.

El rango de hora cada 30 minutos.

Este es un ejemplo que trate de hacer para despues reemplazar los datos de la base de datos. Pero al no tener un total de horas de la tabla `carga horaria` no puedo avanzar y tampoco se como hacerlo.

```
<?php
$valorporhora = '320';

$mifecha = '14:30';
$horaagregada = '6'; //6 horas

$NuevaFecha = strtotime ( '+'.$horaagregada.'hour' , strtotime ($mifecha) ) ; 
//$NuevaFecha = strtotime ( '+18 minute' , $NuevaFecha ) ; 
//$NuevaFecha = strtotime ( '+30 second' , $NuevaFecha ) ; 
$NuevaFecha = date ( 'H:m' , $NuevaFecha); 

echo $NuevaFecha.' Horas';

//resultado: 20:08 Horas
?>
```

> Un dato. Tanto `horaestimada` como `horainicio`, `horafin` y
>   `totalhora` esta creado como `VARCHAR`.

Carga horaria. Son dos `select`, uno para hora de inicio y otro para hora final.

```
<?php
$today = new DateTime();
$aHours = array();
$oStart = new DateTime('now');
$oStart->setTime(0, 0);
$oEnd = clone $oStart;
$oEnd->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));

while ($oStart->getTimestamp() < $oEnd->getTimestamp()) {
    $aHours[] = $oStart->format('H');
    $oStart->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
}

// Rango de 30 minutos
$halfs = array(
    '0',
    '30',
);

$currentHalf = $today->format('i') - ($today->format('i') % 30);
?>

<select name="horasa">
<option value="-1">Hora</option>
<?php foreach ($aHours as $hour): ?>
    <?php foreach ($halfs as $half): ?>
        <option value="<?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $half); ?>" <?= ($hour == $today->format('H') && $half == $currentHalf) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
            <?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $half); ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no creas las columnas como tipo `TIME`en base de datos? Luego utilizas la funcion `TIMEDIFF(horafin, horainicio)` y ya tienes un valor con el que trabajar.

Comment: Ah, bueno gracias, voy a probarlo!